FastAPI object from middleware to actual endpoint
I try to build a middleware for my app.
I need a way to create some object in my middleware function and i want to have access to that object in a next endpoint method . Please see my code example .
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    myObject = MyClass(request)
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    return response

@app.get("/")
def read_root(arg:str):
    data = myObject.build_data(arg)
    return {"Hello": "World", "data": data}

Is it possible to do? How to do this correctly?
Also, if it is not possible to create new object and pass it to an endpoint code. Maybe i can create kinda "global variable" for object? But how will it work in terms of multithreading?
app = FastAPI()
myObject = MyClass()

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    myObject.use_request(request)
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    return response

@app.get("/")
def read_root(arg:str):
    data = myObject.build_data(arg)
    return {"Hello": "World", "data": data}

Will this work fine or there will be some specifics of multithreading etc?

You can attach any data to request.state inside your middleware, and then read it inside your controller. You do request.state.my_object = MyClass(request) in your middleware and you access request.state.my_object inside your controller (I'd usually recommend not making MyClass depend on the request object itself if it's not actually working with the request itself). https://www.starlette.io/requests/#other-state -- I'd also mention that your example seems like it could just be a regular dependency instead of a middleware from what you've shared.

The answer posted by MatsLindh in a comment works fine.
Also i have got the full answer here https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/discussions/12250
import time

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    myObject = MyClass(request)
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    return response

@app.get("/")
def read_root(arg:str):
    data = myObject.build_data(arg)
    return {"Hello": "World", "data": data}

